# Brave Browser's Bundled Tor reveals browser through search, is this a privacy issue?

Tags: security, exit-relays, fingerprinting, url

### Description

When using private window Tor mode I was surprised to see that Brave passes a browser identifier in the url of the search.

It seems having `&t=brave` in the url makes identifying the user easier.

Since any tor nodes monitoring the URL address can tell which browser you're using *(and Brave currently only has around 5 million active monthly users, of which only a small percentage use Tor)*.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Open private browsing window with tor
2. Right click on highlighted text
3. Click on "Search DuckDuckGo for"
4. View url and see `&t=brave`

[image]

[image]

Alternatively you can search using the URL bar which will also append `&t=brave` to the DuckDuckGo URL.

### Question

[Should this be considered a privacy issue](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/2440#issuecomment-448696504)? Could Tor exit nodes use this information to narrow down the possible identity of a user based on knowing they are using Brave?

Comment: what does brave have to do with Tor?

Comment: a general advise: don't use brave at all!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy it ships with Tor browser built in. Also the lead of security is Yan Zhu who was a contributor to the Tor Project.

Comment: well... a part of the privacy-concept is to sink in the sea of not distinguishable Tor-users (that's a reason why [*Tails*](https://tails.boum.org/) does not use different addons, settings etc.), so splitting the user base by using a different browser isn't a good idea. - and not to mention, that they are still a company and want resp. must sell their "product"... whether it is their software or their users. the last time i reviewed Brave, their business plan was to locally replace ads and inject their own, which is IMHO questionable.

Comment: btw: i saw that they are using code of [*Privacy Badger*](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger), whose concept is suspected to result in distinguishable profiles of users. - don't get me wrong: *Privacy Badger* is really nice and definitely better to use than browsing with a plain browser, but i wouldn't advise it in conjunction with Tor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Tor exit nodes can't see the full path of a URL, only the domain (and subdomain if one is used).

The full path including the referrer URL in this case is encrypted.

See [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38727920/773263) for more details.